# jQuery/JS - Wait for JSON chunk to be done processing before starting the next chunk

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to split my 700 entries JSON file and process them in chunks of 20.

I've come up with the following code, which works fine when the operations in save.php don't take too long. However, the JSON file also contains urls to images that I need to download in save.php making the process take longer than 300 milliseconds and causing the next chunk to be fired.

I could of course adjust the time, but what I really want is that the script moves on to the next chunk once the entire operation in save.php is done. Is there any way to do that?
Thanks!

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(products) {

    var time = 300;
    var chunk = 20;

    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i += chunk) {

        (function(index) {

            setTimeout(function() { 

                var out = jQuery.param({'products':products.slice(index, index + chunk)});

                $.post('save.php', out, function(result) {

                  $('.log').append(result);

                });

            }, time);

            time += 300;

        })(i);

    }

});
```

Comment: You could use [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async) will probably do what you need. You can iterate over your entries limiting the number of councurrent operations.

```
async.eachLimit(products, 20,function(elem, cb){
    var out = jQuery.param({'product':elem});
        $.post('save.php', out, function(result) {
        $('.log').append(result);
        cb();
    });
},
function(){
     console.log("success");
})
```

**EDIT** With this approach you have to do one post for each product, but you can do 20 parallel posts, which isn't "nice", dunno if this is an issue for you?

Comment: What should I replace `index` with for `out` to slice the array?

Comment: I've updated my answer, give it a look. But I think you can't, you should be sending 20 parallel post at a time with this approach.

Comment: Works like a charm. However, I get feedback appended to the log per each result, so I am not sure what the Limit is doing in this case?

Comment: try an look over [here](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), eachLimit the same as each but runs a maximum of limit async operations at a time. So makes the first 20 requests, when all of them have finish, it goes over the second 20 products, and so on. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes it's perfect. I did need the key to populate a css progress bar, so I changed it to forEachOfLimit. Thank you sir!